# Sorting JSON data in tableview using two separate values | Swift

Tags: swift

**Currently I have the following criteria for sorting tableview values in ascending order:**

```
self.valuestruct = try JSONDecoder().decode([ExampleStructure].self,from:data)
self.structure.sort { $0.Value1 < $1. Value1 }
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

**The JSON decoding structure looks like the following:**

```
struct ExampleStructure: Codable {
    let Value1, Value2, Value3: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
       case Value1 = "Value1"
       case Value2 = "Value2"
       case Value3 = "Value3"
    }
}
```

**Is it possible to add a second criteria to this sorting method by doing something like this:**

`Value1 and Value2 < Value1 and Value2`

Comment: self.structure.sort { $0.Value1 < $1. Value1 && $0.Value2 < $1.Value2 } ??

Comment: @Quinn's logic would work as well, but from your question I felt tuples were more suited for your requirement

Comment: Unrelated but please conform to the naming convention and name all struct members with starting lowercase letter.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can use tuples:

```swift
let a = ExampleStructure(Value1: "1", Value2: "2", Value3: "3")
let b = ExampleStructure(Value1: "4", Value2: "5", Value3: "6")

print((a.Value1, a.Value2) < (b.Value1, b.Value2)) // prints true
```

So in your case

```
self.structure.sort { ($0.Value1, $0.Value2) < ($1.Value1, $1.Value2) }
```

As commented by [Quinn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9779471/quinn), standard logic operators would do the trick as well:

```
self.structure.sort { $0.Value1 < $1.Value1 && $0.Value2 < $1.Value2 }
```

Comment: Please feel free to mark this answer correct if it solved your problem